# What do apostrophes mean in java

Tags: java

in the book i'm learning from i came across this code snippit:

```
while (i < len) { 
char c = s.charAt(i); 
if (c == ’(’) { 
count = count + 1; 
} else if (c == ’)’) { 
count = count - 1; 
} 
i = i + 1; 
}
```

what do the apostrophes mean in `(c == '(')` ? also isn't there a syntax error here? it looks like `(c == '(')` needs another ) at the end of it.

what about here : `else if (c == ’)’)`    ?

Comment: You could create `char` variables for the `'('` and `')'` so you wouldn't notice how they resemble opening/closing parentheses in the code.

Comment: Ahh... a nested bracket matcher that doesn't try to solve the problem use regular expressions!

Comment: @David: you're mixing ' (hexcode 27) and ’ in your example. The 0x27 ASCII apostrophe is used in Java to enclose a *char*. In your example your checking to see if the *char* c is a left or a right parenthesis. And there's no error, besides the fact that unedited your code won't compile to the fact that you're not using the correct ' apostrophe.

Comment: Lol! How many David's XD

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They surround a `char` in the same way that `"` surround a string like `String s = "a string"`.

In the code, it is testing if `c` is a `(` character.

(BTW, you have `’` characters in your code, and I think these should be `'` characters.)

Comment: The confusing thing is that the character being used is a parenthesis (or round bracket) and that is making the code look odd. An IDE or text editor with syntax colouring might help here if you have access to one.

Comment: what do you mean its testing if c is a ( character. what does it mean to be a ( character?

Comment: It is going through a String of text and actually checking each 'letter' to see if it is a left round bracket ie. `(` or a right round bracket `)`. So the string "The track is 1 mile (1.6km) long." has 1 occurrence each of the `(` and `)` characters.

Comment: a "char" or "character" is a letter, number or symbol. In this case ( and ) are symbols.  it's looking for an open or close parentheses in the string referenced by the variable "s".  `if (c == 'a')` would be looking for the letter 'a', likewise `if (c == '(')` is looking for an open parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes indicate a character as opposed to a string which is wrapped in double quotes. So:
    char c = 'a';
    string s = "a string";

Answer (score 0):

Apostrophe here is used to surround one char value.
With String you use "", with char you use ''